# "22-jährig" as predicative adjective?

Tags: adjective

From *Spiegel Magazine*:

> Dort machte er 2003 die Bekanntschaft mit einem Mann, der sein Leben verändern sollte: dem selbst ernannten Prediger Farid Benyettou, damals **22-jährig**, der mit seinem langen Haar ...

[This dictionary](http://www.dict.cc/?s=22+j%C3%A4hrig) lists *22-jährig* as an attributive adjective. In the text, however, it seems to be used as a predicative adjective, not placed in front of a noun. So, is it not necessarily attributive after all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure we are on the same page, predicative means that it is part of the predicate and it, thus, follows the linking verb (in a sentence following the word order S-P-O).

Predicative would look like that:

```
Subject Predicate
Er      ist 22-jährig.
He      is 22-year-old.
```

I'd consider the German one colloquially OK, but better would be:

```
Subject Predicate
Er      ist 22 (Jahre alt).
He      is 22 (years old).
```

Attributive would mean that it is part of a noun phrase

```
Noun phrase
Der 22-jährige Mann
The 22-year-old man
```

In the example sentence, however, it's an insertion <sup>1</sup>.
You can look at this in two ways. Either it's just a postpositional attributive adjective (then it's certainly fine) or you could think of it as an ellipse:

```
Noun phrase insertion
Der Mann    , [er war] damals 22-jährig, ...
The man     , [he was] 22-year-old then, ...
```

In that case, again, it'd be nicer to use the proper way (i.e. *22 Jahre alt*), but this usage is acceptable–at least in German.

So, I wouldn't consider it wrong per se. Depending on how you look at it, you could argue against it. On the other hand, for stylistic reasons (especially in literary, but also in newspaper), it's definitely fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not sure about the correct term. Apposition came to my mind but that's restricted to noun phrase I believe. In that case it's an 'adjektivischer Einschub' or something like that.

Comment: I still don't know the proper term, but for some reference: "Infinitiv-, Partizip- oder Adjektivgruppen werden durch Kommas abgetrennt, wenn sie als Zusätze oder Nachträge anzusehen sind, die einem Nomen oder Pronomen nachgestellt sind: 'Der Sommer, heiß und trocken, ist dort eine ungünstige Reisezeit.'" [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Zusatz.html?lang=en#Anchor-Infinitiv-47857)